# Category links including all posts

Tags: loop

Really rusty on the wordpress front.

I am using custom permalinks  `/%category%/%postname%/` as well as the `WP No Category Base` plugin, so my urls look like this: http://www.url.com/parent_category/child_category/

I only have an index.php set up at the moment, with the most basic loop possible:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php query_posts(); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    

<div class="post">
   <?php the_title(); ?>
   <br />
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>    
<?php else: ?>   
<?php endif;?>
```

The problem is, all posts are coming through, instead of just the posts in the category represented by the url. I didn't think I needed a custom query, because the link that took me to the particular url should have been carried across. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<?php query_posts(); ?>` in your code is causing the global query to be reset to show all posts instead of the one set by your rewrite rules.  You should remove that line.